# A simple android application using Google Maps API V2 occurs error

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing an android application using Google Maps API v2.
I've selected the template activity "Google Maps Activity" in Android Studio 2.2.
When I run this template, it throws com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536.

I only have a template program runnning, I don't know why the error occurred.
Please help me.

Gradle Console showed the following:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportPaletteV72400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAwareness980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCastFramework980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesClearcut980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGass980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesInstantapps980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlaces980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanager980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerApi980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthCommon980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthModule980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseConfig980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCrash980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorage980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorageCommon980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Incremental compilation of 1 classes completed in 7.733 secs.
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:packageInstantRunResourcesDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:fastDeployDebugExtractor UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkManifestChangesDebug
:app:transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDependencyCheckerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesAndNative_libsWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClasses_enhancedWithInstantReloadDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugTasks UP-TO-DATE
:app:preColdswapDebug
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 9.446 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

put this line

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

in your `defaultConfig` block in your `build.gradle` file.

Hope this will help

Comment: I tried to that. The program passed compiling, but it failed to execute. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

For the error multiindex, you can try:

- clean project
- Manually deleting the /app/build and /build directories from my project
- Invalidating Gradle Cache and restarting Android Studio

After that, you can try to add

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Maybe you need [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7)

> The Gradle build script dependency identifier for this library is as
>   follows:
>
> `com.android.support:multidex:1.0.`

For your example, you can follow [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding all the Google Play Services APIs to your project. You just need to add the dependencies that you are going to use.

So, in your `build.gradle` change your play-services dependencies from this (adding all the Google Play Services APIs):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
}
```

To this (adding only Google Maps API):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
}
```